# Run app in simulator AND iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios-simulator

Ok, so I have a TTS library (Text to speech) and I can get my app to run on the iPhone and the simulator, but I have to change a directory in the build settings depending on where I want to run my app. How can I get the app to work on the simulator and iPhone, but without changing a thing in the build settings.

The TTS engine has two data files (one for sim and one for iPhone) if I have a path to both and I try running on simulator then I get a linker error saying the data file is not supported for armv7. If I have a path to both and I try running on iPhone then I get a linker error saying the data file is not supported for i386. If I have a path to the iPhone data file ONLY and run on iPhone then it works.If I have a path to the simulator data file ONLY and run on simulator then it works.

Anyone come across this problem?

Comment: Did you try to set different configurations for device and simulator by using "Product" - "Manage Schemes..."?

Comment: hmm, don't think so, am I suppose to?

Answer (score 0):

If you have two libraries for different architectures, you can actually merge them together using the "lipo" command. Just do:

```
lipo -create <i386 lib> <arm lib> -o <output>
```

Then use the created file instead of the original two.